# GSON Deserialization of subtypes in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, gson, deserialization

I'm not sure if this is a limitation, a bug or just bad use of GSON. I need to have a hierarchy of Kotlin objects (parent with various subtypes) and I need to deserialize them with GSON. The deserialized object has correct subtype **but its field enumField is actually null**.

First I thought this is because the field is passed to the "super" constructor but then I found out that "super" works well for string, just enum is broken.

See this example:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
import com.google.gson.typeadapters.RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory

open class Parent(val stringField: String,
                  val enumField: EnumField) {

    enum class EnumField {
        SUBTYPE1,
        SUBTYPE2,
        SUBTYPE3
    }
}


class Subtype1() : Parent("s1", EnumField.SUBTYPE1)
class Subtype2(stringField: String) : Parent(stringField, EnumField.SUBTYPE2)
class Subtype3(stringField: String, type: EnumField) : Parent(stringField, type)

val subtypeRAF = RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.of(Parent::class.java, "enumField")
        .registerSubtype(Subtype1::class.java, Parent.EnumField.SUBTYPE1.name)
        .registerSubtype(Subtype2::class.java, Parent.EnumField.SUBTYPE2.name)
        .registerSubtype(Subtype3::class.java, Parent.EnumField.SUBTYPE3.name)

fun main() {
    val gson = GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapterFactory(subtypeRAF)
            .create()

    serializeAndDeserialize(gson, Subtype1()) // this works (but not suitable)
    serializeAndDeserialize(gson, Subtype2("s2")) // broken
    serializeAndDeserialize(gson, Subtype3("s3", Parent.EnumField.SUBTYPE3)) // broken
}

private fun serializeAndDeserialize(gson: Gson, obj: Parent) {
    println("-----------------------------------------")
    val json = gson.toJson(obj)
    println(json)
    val obj = gson.fromJson(json, Parent::class.java)
    println("stringField=${obj.stringField}, enumField=${obj.enumField}")
}
```

**Any ideas how to achieve to deserialization of `enumField`?**

(deps: *com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5*, *org.danilopianini:gson-extras:0.2.1*)

P.S.: Note that I have to use `RuntimeAdapterFactory` because I have subtypes with different set of fields (I did not do it in the example so it is easier to understand).

Comment: Can you post error logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gson requires constructors without arguments to work properly (see deep-dive into Gson code below). Gson constructs raw objects and then use reflection to populate fields with values.

So if you just add some argument-less dummy constructors to your classes that miss them, like this:

```
class Subtype1() : Parent("s1", EnumField.SUBTYPE1)
class Subtype2(stringField: String) : Parent(stringField, EnumField.SUBTYPE2) {
    constructor() : this("")
}
class Subtype3(stringField: String, type: EnumField) : Parent(stringField, type) {
    constructor() : this("", EnumField.SUBTYPE3)
}
```

you will get the expected output:

```
-----------------------------------------
{"stringField":"s1","enumField":"SUBTYPE1"}
stringField=s1, enumField=SUBTYPE1
-----------------------------------------
{"stringField":"s2","enumField":"SUBTYPE2"}
stringField=s2, enumField=SUBTYPE2
-----------------------------------------
{"stringField":"s3","enumField":"SUBTYPE3"}
stringField=s3, enumField=SUBTYPE3
```

## Gson deep-dive

If you want to investigate the internals of Gson, a tip is to add an `init { }` block to `Subtype1` since it works and then set a breakpoint there. After it is hit you can move up the call stack, step through code, set more breakpoints etc, to reveal the details of how Gson constructs objects.

By using this method, you can find the Gson internal class `com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor` and its method `newDefaultConstructor(Class<? super T>)` that has code like this (I have simplified for brevity):

```
    final Constructor<? super T> constructor = rawType.getDeclaredConstructor(); // rawType is e.g. 'class Subtype3'
    Object[] args = null;
    return (T) constructor.newInstance(args);
```

i.e. it tries to construct an object via a constructor without arguments. In your case for `Subtype2` and `Subtype3`, the code will result in a caught exception:

```
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) { // java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Subtype3.<init>()
      return null; // set breakpoint here to see
    }
```

i.e. your original code fails since Gson can't find constructors without arguments for `Subtype2` and `Subtype3`.

In simple cases, the problem with missing argument-less constructors is worked around with the `newUnsafeAllocator(Type, final Class<? super T>)`-method in `ConstructorConstructor`, but with `RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory` that does not work correctly.

Comment: This works even when `RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory` is not used

Comment: @Mohanakrrishna actually it works for me with `RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory`, Marking this as correct answer and "paying" the bounty.

Comment: @zdenda.online Dude, you really waited till last minute to award that bounty! I didn't expect to get any reward; I thought you had forgot about your bounty. I really appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: @Enselic No, I just kind of lost my hopes and didn't visit to stackoverflow for a while ;)

Answer (score 2):

I may be missing something in what you're trying to achieve, but is it necessary to use the `RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory`?  If we take out the line where we register that in the Gson builder, so that it reads

```
val gson = GsonBuilder()
    .create()
```

Then the output returns the enum we would expect, which looks to be serialising / deserialising correctly.  I.e. the output is:

```
-----------------------------------------
{"stringField":"s1","enumField":"SUBTYPE1"}
stringField=s1, enumField=SUBTYPE1
-----------------------------------------
{"stringField":"s2","enumField":"SUBTYPE2"}
stringField=s2, enumField=SUBTYPE2
-----------------------------------------
{"stringField":"s3","enumField":"SUBTYPE3"}
stringField=s3, enumField=SUBTYPE3
```

It also may be an idea to implement `Serializable` in Parent. i.e.

```
open class Parent(val stringField: String, val enumField: EnumField) : Serializable {

    enum class EnumField {
        SUBTYPE1,
        SUBTYPE2,
        SUBTYPE3
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Nelson. I need RuntimeAdapterFactory as every subtype has different set of fields. I updated the original answer to it is clear. I didn't want to mess up sample code so it points to the problem only.

Adding Serializable to Parent did not help :-(

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `@SerializedName` annotation to each enum.

```
enum class EnumField {
    @SerializedName("subtype1")
    SUBTYPE1,
    @SerializedName("subtype2")
    SUBTYPE2,
    @SerializedName("subtype3")
    SUBTYPE3
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried that already (before) posting the question but that does not help.